# Duplicate message on BLE after readRemoteRssi?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

After calling `gatt.readRemoteRssi()` I suddenly started getting the same data multiple times.

Has anyone seen such thing in the past? I can reproduce this on several phones (both cheap LG+Samsung phones).